# javascript space difference between name with and without spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this part of code to create a list of buttons

```
obj.zones[0].forEach(function(entry) {
        listDesZones+='<button onclick=enableModification("'+ entry.nomZone +'","'+ entry._id.$oid +'")>' + entry.nomZone + '</button><br>';
});
```

But when the entry.nomZone contains spaces I have a problem 
you can see in firebug

[image]

what do you think guys about that ?

Comment: you want to get rid of spaces ?

Comment: A space shouldn't cause that issue. Could you show a full example of the issue, including the value of `entry.nomZone`

Comment: I think in your 'entry.nomZone' you have a double quote and not a space... post more code. Or put a "console.log(entry.nomZone);" and post the value of console.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace space:

```
entry.nomZone.replace(/\s/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
listDesZones+='<button onclick=enableModification("'+ entry.nomZone +'","'+ entry._id.$oid +'")>' + entry.nomZone + '</button><br>';
```

to this:

```
listDesZones+="<button onclick=\"enableModification('"+ entry.nomZone +"','"+ entry._id.$oid +"')\">" + entry.nomZone + "</button><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the leading and trailing white-space before generating the markup.

I am using an Array to generate the markup

```
var list = [" Button1 ","Button2","Button3 ","Button4"];
```

Here the first item has leading and trailing white-spaces

Check the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4m7f2gdu/1/) markup generated for `Button1` item (By Inspect Element in browser feature)

To fix this you can use [jquery $.trim() api](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove the leading and trailing white-spaces.

So you can update the code as below to fix this like

```
obj.zones[0].forEach(function(entry) {
        listDesZones+="<button onclick=enableModification('"+ $.trim(entry.nomZone) +"','"+ $.trim(entry._id.$oid) +"')>" + $.trim(entry.nomZone) + "</button><br>";
});
```

I have also replaced single-quote with double-quotes and vice-versa as the markup generated is using double-quotes to enclose the function in the markup-event.

Hope it works for you